# What is the speed or accuracy difference between number crunching in python vs. nodejs?

Tags: javascript, python, numpy, bigdata, scientific-computing

Python has numpy and nodejs has [numjs](https://github.com/nicolaspanel/numjs).

I suppose each works natively and uniquely in the different Operating Systems it is installed on, and each is not exactly the "sandboxed" version running through the interpreter.

There is [paralleljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/paralleljs) for parallel programming, and [mapred - for map reduce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mapred).

Still Python has Spyder and Anaconda and everything for scientific (matlab like) functionality and high speed parallel computing on big data (like Disco) while nodejs and Javascript do not, or are not used for this.

Is there any reason for this other than historical? Is there better accuracy or higher speed available in Python and not in Javascript? Or perhaps better interactivity with native OS calls or with C and C++ libraries? (I just read a post that showed how to do that as well...)

Comment: `numpy` is 10+ years old, building on older packages.  `numjs` appears to be 2 years ago, and largely the work of one person. `numpy` has a lot of compiled `C` code, and can use other packages written in Fortran and C++.  I only see `js` source code on the `numjs` repository.

Comment: So you say its just historically the lack of developed tools and communities around JS because NodeJS and NPM are newer?

Comment: Disco core is in Erlang with python coordinating jobs.  Many of the mathematical things either suggested or implied in your post are also along the same line; they access C types, LLVM, CUDA or other libraries and languages.

Comment: No 'just' about my comment.  You were asking about `numjs`.  Comparing `python` and `nodejs` is a different question.  As for speed, just run your own tests.

Comment: You should tag this question with `[numjs]`  :)

Comment: can't there is no tag numjs (which shows how unpopular that is). OK So the answer is that in actuality most of the python scientific libraries go to C. and therefore the lack of nodejs packages is just a thing of historical choice.